# Oracle Apex: Display Date With Specific Calendar

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a date column in my table which is needed to be displayed in a Interactive Data Grid

The problem is in display format of the date, which is displayed in Gregorian calendar, I tried changing **Source Type** of the column to **Sql Expression** but after that I cannot use filter on that column

Should I alter session each time on page load event? or there is a straight way to do this?

Comment: This is strictly an ApEx question; I removed your other tags. The proper way to solve your question is through ApEx settings, not through changes to SQL code.